Dropping observations by date
I have a date variable in Stata MP 17.0 doi which is in %td format.
I want to drop specific dates but the commands I am using either do not drop observations or show type mismatch.
I changed the format to %tdNN/DD/CCYY but still the outcome is same.
Steps I did- enter image description here

Hi Samira.  Dates are non-trivial, but careful study of this might help:  https://www.stata.com/manuals/u25.pdf

A daily date variable is numeric, so comparison with a string yields a type mismatch.
The numeric expression you typed just yields a small fraction because the /s are interpreted as division.
. di 03/19/2024
.00007801

There are various ways to do what you want. One is
drop if date == mdy(3, 19, 2024)

Changing the display format doesn't change what is stored.
There is no good understanding of dates without reading the help on dates.
help dates 

